# nodejs seems to be installed but it1s not available

Tags: apt, nodejs

I am having trouble with installation of nodejs version 16 (I tried with v14 and v18 with same results). The default version for ubuntu is v12 but I need higher.

I followed instructions from https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debmanual

And the result:

```
user@:~$ nodejs -v
Command 'nodejs' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nodejs
user@:~$ sudo apt install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (16.18.0-deb-1nodesource1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

Thanks for your time, Mark

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to install it from **Snap**, it was way easier for me: https://snapcraft.io/node. You can also choose the version you want to install from the drop-down provided there and to test if the install was successful try running the command `node -v`, this should print out the version you chose to install.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Yes @David I need at least 50 reputation to comment